# Is there a way to Reset multiple cells from TRUE to FALSE?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2021

I am very new to Excel, so if you have any solutions please explain it like I probably have no clue.

As shown in this image.

[image]

I have multiple check boxes in different cells.

I would like to have a single form control that will reset all these cells to FALSE.

If any further details are needed, I will try and provide them.

I did try a toggle button and link it to multiple cells in `Developer\>Controls\>Properties` but the input just disappears as soon as I clicked off `LinkedCell`.